# "To compensate" or "compensate for"?

Tags: grammar

As I'm no native speaker, I wonder about the usage for *compensate*.
I'm writing a title of a paper.
Is it:

> "*Compensating for X Effects*"

or

> "*Compensating X Effects*" ?

In this case I want to express that the methods introduced in the paper decrease/get rid off the "X effects". The second one sounds to me as if the "effects" would get some kind of compensation. Yet, I'm not sure.

Comment: I think you might want to check the precise definition of *compensate*. It definitely doesn't mean *get rid of*. You might be better off sticking to *decrease*, or similar (*reduce*, *counteract*, etc.), where at least you already know the word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *New Oxford American Dictionary* has an example of the meaning you're using:

> **compensate**
>   [among others]
>    • act to neutralize or correct (a deficiency or abnormality in a physical property or effect): *the output voltage rises, **compensating for** the original fall*.

It used transitively to mean “recompense someone for loss, suffering, or injury” (same source). Example: *Pakistan to Compensate Victims of U.S. Airstrike*.